# Add HTML elements dynamically with JavaScript inside DIV with specific ID

Tags: javascript

Ok, people, I need your help. I've found some code here on Stackoverflow (can't find that link) which generate HTML code dynamically via JS. Here is code:

```
function create(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
      }
        return frag;
    }

    var fragment = create('<div class="someclass"><a href="www.example.com"><p>some text</p></a></div>'); 

    document.body.insertBefore(fragment, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

This code works just fine! But the generated code appears on top of page, right below `body` tag. I would like to generate that code inside empty `div` with specific `id="generate-here"`.

So output will be:

```
<div id="generate-here">
    <!-- Here is generated content -->
</div>
```

I know that I can't see generated content with "view source". I only need to generate that content just in this particular place with `#generate-here`. I'm Javascript noob, so if anyone can just rearrange this code that will be perfect. Thanks a lot!

P.S. I know how to do this with Jquery, but I need native and pure JavaScript in this case.

Comment: You can view the actual html on the page with firebug: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that :) But more important is to generate that code on that particular place.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you need to do is change the last line. This will add the created element as the **last** child of the div:

```
document.getElementById("generate-here").appendChild(fragment);
```

This will add the created element as the **first** child of the div:

```
var generateHere = document.getElementById("generate-here");
generateHere.insertBefore(fragment, generateHere.firstChild);
```

You can also use innerHTML to just replace everything with new text (as you do in your `create` function). Obviously this one doesn't require you to keep the `create` function because you need an html string instead of a DOM object.

```
var generateHere = document.getElementById("generate-here");
generateHere.innerHTML = '<div class="someclass"><a href="www.example.com"><p>some text</p></a></div>';
```

Comment: I don't know why, but that #generate-here is still empty. I've tried both codes, and it doesn't work :/

Comment: @MiljanPuzović did you keep all your other code the same and just change the last line? I edited to clarify. :)

Comment: Yes, i've just changed the last line :) And that didn't work. I'll try now with innerHTML.

Comment: Interesting, they all work for me in this example. Just comment out the one you want to try; I listed all three. http://jsfiddle.net/XydQ9/

Comment: I don't see even from example that is working :/ See picture http://i.imgur.com/mke2H.jpg I'm using Chrome, maybe is some bug in Chrome.... No, i've looked also from Firefox, same problem.

Comment: You need to uncomment one of the blocks of code and then click run to see the result (uncomment by removing the `/*` and `*/` surrounding the one you want to try.) My bad, should've been more specific. Plus I said comment out instead of uncomment earlier...

Comment: I got it after few minutes, sorry :) removed first block of code and it works http://jsfiddle.net/XydQ9/1/ :D

Comment: Here is live page http://webdesign.miljanpuzovic.com/ Look at footer, you'll see "test". There should be appear created content... I've put JS code inside tinybox.js, on the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14907/discussion-between-crazyjugglerdrummer-and-miljan-puzovic)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Let's create a function to return us an ordered HTML listview. Note we are passing in an array of data:

```
function createListView(spacecrafts){
    var listView=document.createElement('ol');
    for(var i=0;i<spacecrafts.length;i++)
    {
        var listViewItem=document.createElement('li');
        listViewItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(spacecrafts[i]));
        listView.appendChild(listViewItem);
    }
    return listView;
}
```

Step 2. Then let's display our listview in your div:

```
document.getElementById("displaySectionID").appendChild(createListView(myArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution example

```
function divHTML(img, d1, r1, r2){
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const newContent = `
    <img src="`+img+`" width=50%>
    <h1 style="color:white">`+d1+`</h1>
    <button onclick="dom1.value='A'">A</button><i>`+r1+`</i><br>
    <button onclick="dom1.value='B'">B</button><i>`+r2+`</i><br>
    <input id="dom1" type="text"><hr>
    `;
    newDiv.innerHTML = newContent;
    const currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
}

divHTML("https://images-cdn.kahoot.it/decf7162-f24b-464b-b2e7-2cca47ae0b42?auto=webp", "qual è la scrittura giusta?", "opzione 1", "opzione 2"
    );
```