# Using Javascript to display content if certain criteria is met

Tags: javascript

I have 2 sets of banner code for displaying banners:

1) Ad server code which gets blocked by AdBlock
2) Plain HTML banner insertion which AdBlock does not block

My questions is:

How can I use Javascript (or something else, for that matter) to insert the plain Javascript banner code if AdBlock is detected.

For reference, I found this AdBlock detection code:

```
document.write('<div id="tester" style="display:none">an advertisemen</div>');

<script type="text/javascript" src="advert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById("tester") == undefined) 
{ 
document.write(' TEXT TO DISPLAY IF ADBLOCK IS ACTIVE'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using code provide by you:

```
document.write('<div id="tester" style="display:none">an advertisemen</div>');

<script type="text/javascript" src="advert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById("tester") == undefined) 
{ 
document.write('HTML banner code here'); 
} else {
docuement.write('Ad Server code here')
}
```

Both of your HTML banner and Ad Server codes will be in JavaScript which write a div to the core HTML file at a specific DOM point.
Example: [Add HTML elements dynamically with JavaScript inside DIV with specific ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805251/add-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript-inside-div-with-specific-id)