# jquery - add div to the child dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, warnings

I want to add this warning div dynamically after the **SecondDiv** in my HTML.
Please suggest how simply we can achieve this in jquery.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">

    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive" id="FirstDiv">

        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="table-responsive" id="SecondDiv">

        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="table-responsive" id="ThirdDiv">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**WARNING DIV:**

```
<div class="note note-warning"> 
    <div class="block-warning"> 
        <h4 class="block"> <i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i> Warning! Some Header Goes Here</h4>
        <p>Warning </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamically` here, in what context?

Comment: document.getElementById('SecondDiv').appendChild(document.getElementById('warningDiv');. I'd put an ID in your warning div to add this way

Comment: $("#SecondDiv").append($("#warningDiv").html())

Comment: on what event you want to add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add HTML elements dynamically with JavaScript inside DIV with specific ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805251/add-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript-inside-div-with-specific-id)

Answer (score 1):

As per javascript you can use [**Element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

One suggestion is to use an Id to the warning div:

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById('SecondDiv'), // target element
  wd = document.getElementsByClassName('note')[0].cloneNode(true); // get a new copy of warning div

wd.id = 'warningDiv'; // put an id to this div

d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', wd.outerHTML); // place the div after target div
document.getElementById('warningDiv').style.display = 'block'; // show the div if hidden
```

```css
.note{display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="note note-warning">
  <h1>Warning</h1>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive" id="SecondDiv">
  SecondDiv
</div>
```

---

With jQuery, you can use `.after()`:

```js
var d1 = $('#SecondDiv');
var wd = $('.note');
d1.after(wd);
wd.show();
```

```css
.note {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="note note-warning">
  <h1>Warning</h1>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive" id="SecondDiv">
  SecondDiv
</div>
```

Comment: @thisOneGuy just updating with jQuery too.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that it is on page load.
You can do it like this

```
$(function() {
    $('.note.note-warning').appendTo($('#SecondDiv'));    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it  like following using `after` function.

```
$('#SecondDiv').after('<div class="note note-warning"><div class="block-warning"><h4 class="block"> <i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i> Warning! Some Header Goes Here</h4><p>Warning </p></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
   document.getElementById('SecondDiv').appendChild(document.getElementById('warnin‌​gDiv');.
```

I'd put an ID in your warning div to add this way.

Just noticed you said JQUERY.

```
$('#warningDiv').appendTo($('#SecondDiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .selected{
        background-color : green;
    }
    </style>
<script>





    $(document).ready(function () {

        szDiv = '<div class="note note-warning"> <div class="block-warning"> <h4 class="block"> <i class="demo-icon icon-attention-1 fa"></i> Warning! Some Header Goes Here</h4><p>Warning </p></div></div>';


        $(szDiv).insertAfter("#SecondDiv")
    });




</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">

        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive" id="FirstDiv">

            </div>

            <hr/>

            <div class="table-responsive" id="SecondDiv">

            </div>

            <hr/>

            <div class="table-responsive" id="ThirdDiv">

            </div>

        </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonid").click(function(){
        $("#firstid").clone().appendTo("#secondid");

        return false;

    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="firstid">
<div id="secondid">
any thing in this area will be add
</div>
</div>
<input type"submint" id="buttonid">
</body>
```

Comment: I will try, I am new in here.